# Any way to pass already-initialized parent class to child class instead of initializing it within the child class?

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child, parent, super

Any way to pass already-initialized parent class to child class instead of initializing it within the child class?

Here's an outline of what I would like to do:

```
class P():
    def __init__(self, p_var):
        self.p_var = p_var

    def print_p_var(self):
        print(self.p_var)

class C(P):
    def __init__(self, p_var)
        <??parent class code??> = get_new_p_instance(p_var)

def get_new_p_instance(p_var)
    return P(p_var)

if __name__=="main":
    c_instance = C("P_VAR_STR")
    c.print_p_var()
```

Can this be done? What would have to be in place of the <> there? Or some other way of doing this?

**EDIT:**
Basically, I have a P object, whose class is defined in a different package, and who is returned by get_new_p_instance in that package, and I want to add methods to this P object (hence trying to "import" the P object into my C object so that I can add more of my own methods). What other ways can I do this?

Comment: A child class instance doesn't *contain* an instance of the parent class; it *IS* an instance of the parent class.  You may not want inheritance at all here.

Comment: what do you try to achieve.

perhaps you could show us the class declarations with your pseudo_commands
and then some code using these objects and show us the expected result to make us understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: See my edit for what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: Basically, you have to have a call to the __init__ of the super class in the __init__ of the child class-- alternatively, can you use use an existing super class object instead of initializing a new one?

Comment: Please read John's comment again

Comment: Then recommend a better way to go about it?

Comment: You could define the child class to contain and instance of its parent by passing the an instance of the parent class to its `__init__()` function as an argument, which it then saves as a private attribute of the child instance. The methods of the child class instance would then be able to use this parent instance as necessary.